# Converting float64 to decimal data type for Dynamo db

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a pandas data frame which looks like the below:

```html
Blast_ID    Campaign Campaign ID    Basic rate  Market cost 
ab12                  Glass               20    220
ab34                  Glass                     234
ab56                 Plastic              55    245
ab87                 Plastic              10
```

I converted the columns with float64 data types into an integer with the following code( df being the data frame):

```py
for i in df.columns:
    
        print(i)
        print(df[i].dtypes)
        
        datatype = df[i].dtype
        df = df.fillna(0)
        if datatype == 'float64':
            print('yes')
            df[i] = df[i].astype(int)
```

Still when I am trying to upload this data frame into the dynamo DB with the following code:

```py
    
    myl_list = df1.T.to_dict().values()
    print(myl_list)

   
   
    #read the dynamo resource
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('VisData')
    
    for Blast_ID in myl_list:
        table.put_item(Item=Blast_ID)
```

Is it giving me error that:

```py
"errorMessage": "Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead."
```

How can I solve that? Many Thanks

Comment: `int` is not `Decimal`

Comment: so do I do: import Decimal from Decimal and then Decimal(df[i])   ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting into a string before putting in the table:

```
myl_list = df1.T.to_dict().values()
print(myl_list)

   
   
#read the dynamo resource
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('VisData')

for Blast_ID in myl_list:
    table.put_item(Item=str(Blast_ID))
```

Comment: Yes converting them into string will do, but I do not want to convert certain columns into a string because they would be read from the database for some calculations later. If the columns would be string, it would fail at calculations. Thanks